# Trying to call procedure and pass parameter getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ado.net

I'm trying to call a stored procedure and pass a parameter, but I'm getting an error

> Internal .net framework data provider error 30

on this line of code:

```
conn.CallProcedure("DBPRD.insertUnit(P_ID=:COLUMN1,REV=:COLUMN2,'804',PROP=:COLUMN3,CRTDBY=:COLUMN4)", P_ID,REV,PROP,CRTD_BY);
```

My complete code:

```
public int CallProcedure(string cmdText, params object[] param)
{
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(cmdText, connection);
            OracleTransaction insTransaction;

            connection.Open();

            insTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Transaction = insTransaction;

            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":COLUMN" + (i + 1).ToString(), param[i]);
            }

            try
            {
                rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                insTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                insTransaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of `COLUMN[i + 1]`? This error usually occurs if the parameter has passed value mismatch against parameter type, or the parameter length is shorter than passed value.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto column is string type and i is int type means :COLUMN" + (i + 1).ToString() is string type

Comment: What I actually asked for is data type of `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN2`, `COLUMN3` etc as parameters. Also providing stack trace, error details and `insertUnit` procedure contents may help finding out the issue.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto COLUMN1-string,COLUMN2-int,COLUMN3-string,column4-string,  and error is internal .net framework data provider error 30""

Comment: proc  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertUnit

(PRODUCT_ID1 IN number,REVISION1 IN number,CODE_VALUE1 number,UNIT1 VARCHAR, UPDATED_BY1 IN VARCHAR) AS

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO DBPRODNEW.T_TDC_unit ("TTU_PRODUCT_ID","TTU_REVISION","TTU_CODE_VALUE", "TTU_UNIT", "TTU_UPDATED_BY")
  VALUES (PRODUCT_ID1,REVISION1,CODE_VALUE1,UNIT1,UPDATED_BY1);

  COMMIT;

END;